# Javascript culture always en-us

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, validation, localization

I'm not sure if I understand this code or if I'm using it right, but I was under the impression that in an ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX website I could run javascript like:

```
var c = Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

and it would give me the culture/language settings the user had specified in their browser at the time of the visit. However, for me, it always comes back 'en-US' no matter what language I pick in firefox or IE.

This serverside code however:

```
string[] languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

if (languages == null || languages.Length == 0)
   return null;

try
{
   string language = languages[0].ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
   return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    return null;
}
```

does return the language I have currently set. But I need to do this clientside, because I need to parse a string into a datetime and do some validations before I postback, and the string could be a MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY, or some other such thing.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Ok, I came across this library http://www.datejs.com/. It looks pretty sweet, *and* it has ninjas, so I'm pretty much sold already. But in their doc I noticed that you need to include one of the language specific js files to include. I imagine you'd have to make that determination serverside and emit the proper script include tag, which got me thinking. Am I supposed to be doing this with the ASP.NET AJAX stuff? i.e. checking the serverside culture(which works) and setting the Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in js based on that? I was hoping it would just automagically get it from the browser clientside.

Comment: You should not be using CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language); Just use new CultureInfo(language) instead

Comment: Ok, but that server code is actually working. It's the client side stuff that's giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is based on a value that is sent from the server. To get the server to send the correct value back to the client, you need to set the [EnableScriptGlobalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablescriptglobalization.aspx) property to true on the `ScriptManager` object (it's false by default).

Comment: I set it to true and I still get en-US every time from the JavaScript, and 'English (United Kingdom)' from the server side code. Is there something else I need to set?

Comment: also, there's EnableScriptGlobalization and EnableScriptLocalization. Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

TMK, the browser does not pass any timezone info to server in the first request. You need to do this with Javascript

Comment: The browser always sends the `Accept-Language` header, which ASP.NET uses to determine locale information by default.